# How to reduce Kafka lag? and How to create multiple consumers for same topic?

Tags: python-3.x, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

`def getKafkaConsumer(topicName, kafkaIP, kafkaPort, kafkaConsumerGroup): try: bootstrap = [str(kafkaIP + ':' + kafkaPort)] consumer = KafkaConsumer(topicName, bootstrap_servers = bootstrap, group_id = kafkaConsumerGroup, session_timeout_ms = 30000, api_version = (0,10)) return consumer except: import traceback print('Kafka Error: Check Kafka Consumer Settings!!')`

In my application, producer is producing approx. 1000 messages per second but consumption rate is very slow. In above python code of consumer, please suggest how can I tune kafka parameters to increase consumption. And also suggest how can I create multiple consumers for same Topic.

Comment: you should format your code to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The max number of consumers you can spawn per Kafka topic is equal to the number of partitions in a kafka topic.

So increase the number of partitions and launch multiple consumers.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Could you please elaborate on launching multiple consumers, I mean how to create multiple consumers in kafka-python?

Comment: Launch them as separate applications but connecting to the same consumer group